# Stellar in Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, stellar.js

I'm having issues getting Stellar.js to work for me in Wordpress. I am trying to have certain elements of a page scroll faster or slower than the natural scroll speed of the page, to create a parallax effect.

**Can someone help me fix what I'm doing wrong here?**

In my childtheme folder, I have two files; `js/stellar.min.js` and `js/parallax.js`.

In `functions.php` I have the following to register and enqueue these:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_scripts');
function add_scripts() {
    if ( is_page( 'home' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('stellar', get_template_directory_uri() . "/js/stellar.min.js", array('jquery'));
        wp_enqueue_script('stellar');
        wp_register_script('parallax', get_template_directory_uri() . "/js/parallax.js", array('jquery'));
        wp_enqueue_script('parallax');
    }
}
```

Then in `parallax.js` I have the following:

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery(window).stellar({
        horizontalScrolling: false,
        verticalScrolling: true,
        responsive: false,
        scrollProperty: 'transform',
        positionProperty: 'transform',
        parallaxElements: true
    });
});
```

Lastly, of course, on the elements to be parallax I have `data-stellar-ratio="2"`.

Comment: Use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri` instead of `get_template_directory_uri`. The former will return the URL of your child theme while the later will return the URL of the parent theme. You didn't explain exactly what problem you're having so I'm not sure if that is the only issue.

Comment: The problem I'm having is that nothing is happening. The elements with `data-stellar-ratio` aren't scrolling at any variable speed.

Comment: Is the script being enqueued? When you view the source for the page does it have the script with the correct src?

Comment: Yeah, the script is being enqueued alright.